# Start command remotely and then close connection

Tags: ssh, command, remote, session, nohup

I'm trying to start a trim command on a bunch of servers remotely since these are appliances and we lose support if you change anything like cron jobs locally.

I'm trying to do this:

```
ssh root@192.168.X.X "nohup fstrim /data &"
```

That is executed but the problem is the secure shell is kept open despite nohup and everything. Can I force ssh to just drop the command and pull out immediately?

Just found a similar request via google. There it was solved with

```
screen -d -m ./script
```

Unfortunately screen isn't available on the appliances.

Comment: Does `ssh -f` help? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine

Answer (score 3):

If you've got `screen` installed on the remote servers, try this, which will run the `fstrim` command inside a detached `screen` session. As far as `ssh` is concerned this will appear to exit immediately.

```
ssh root@192.168.X.X screen -S fstrim -md fstrim /data
```

You can reattach to the session with

```
ssh -tt root@192.168.X.X. screen -r fstrim
```

and disconnect again with <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd><kbd>(Ctrl) d</kbd>

The reason your initial command isn't working is because `nohup` can see that *stdout* isn't a terminal and keeps the descriptor open for writing. (If you'd used `ssh -tt` it would have created a pseudotty on the remote side and `nohup` would have seen a terminal.) By redirecting *stdout* explicitly you can get the process to run in the background as you'd expect:

```
ssh -fn root@192.168.X.X "nohup fstrim /data >nohup.out &"
```

Read `man nohup` for the gory details on this now you know what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for "read man for gory details"

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, believe I found the solution:

```
ssh root@192.168.X.X "nohup fstrim /data > /dev/null &"
```

Comment: [My answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545542/100397) explains the _why_ of this.

Answer (score 1):

Is `atd` running on the appliance? If so, you can schedule an immediate `at` job:

```
ssh root@192.168.X.X "echo 'fstrim /data' | at now"
```

Your remote session will terminate immediately, because all it's doing is scheduling the job. The `atd` daemon takes care of actually executing it.